# Status of a javascript var after trying to retrieve an unexisting array entry?

Tags: javascript, arrays, key

Assuming I have a Javascript array and some entries are defined as following:

```
arr["rrr"]=1;
arr["ee"]=2;
arr["qqq"]=22;
...
```

Let's assume one tries to retrieve an entry for an unexisting key, for example:

```
var retr = arr["ppp"];
```

What is the status of the `retr` var? Is it `null` or `undefined` or something else? How can I check whether the array did not contain a valid entry for the provided key? What is the proper test in Javascript? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by a missing key is `undefined`. You can test if the key exists like this :

```
var a = [];
a.hasOwnProperty('k'); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

The result is undefined.
To test you just need to do this:

```
if ("ppp" in arr) {
  // do something
} else {
 // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned value of the undefined array keys is `undefined`. The proper test would be

```
var retr = arr["ppp"];
if(retr!=undefined){
  //retr has some value
}
else{
  //retr is undefined
}
```

Comment: No. Try it with `arr = {ppp: false}`

Answer (score -1):

I tried the code you wrote in Firebug. When I tried to access an entry for an unexisting key

```
var retr=arr["ppp"];
```

it returns null. Hence, retr is equal to null.

```
retr==null; //true
typeof retr=="undefined"; //true
```

Comment: It does not return `null`, it returns `undefined`. That's a different value.

Comment: But if you try arr["ppp"]==null; it returns true. Also, if you try arr["ppp"]==undefined; it returns true and when I tried null==undefined; it also returned true.

Comment: But if you try `null === undefined`, it returns `false`…